# Did Bach ever respond to Taz's criticisms?

Tags: halacha, history, shulchan-aruch, acharonim, yoreh-deah

There are numerous places in the [Taz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_HaLevi_Segal) where R' David HaLevi Segal criticizes the opinions and writings of the [R' Joel Sirkis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Sirkis) (Bach) - who just so happened to be his father-in-law. See for example the [last Taz in Ta'arovos](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_9731_482.pdf).

Is there any record of the Bach responding to the Taz's criticisms? Either in his works, or works of others?

Comment: Was he still alive when Taz was published?

Comment: Good point. I got mixed up on the dates. Seems like Taz was published posthumously.

Comment: Maybe he would have put out a book before the taz came out called 'strange things my son in law told me at the shabbos table and why he's wrong'.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of anywhere where the Bach sets out to address criticisms from the Taz, but he does mention/quote him on a number of occasions.

- Yoreh Deiah siman 147
- Shu"t (yeshanos) siman 74
- Shu"t (yeshanos) siman 93
- Shu"t (yeshanos) siman 94

Additionally, two of the Bach's teshuvos are to the Taz.

- Shu"t (yeshanos)  siman 113
- Shu"t (chadashos) siman 54

(Perhaps there are others as well, for either category?)

Comment: Seems more like a comment to DoubleAA than an answer.